# C++ struct - pointer to pointer and dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, struct

I want to implement a tree trie and insert an example value into the key variable  I am using a pointer to pointer and creating a dynamic array of 100 elements but my application crashes after starting.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

struct node {
  int key;
  node **children;          
};

int main() {
  node *child;          
  child = new node;
  child->children = new node *[100];
  child->children[20]->key = 90;        
  cout<<child->children[20]->key;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and watching the contents of your child/children objects to see if they're what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for `child->children[20]`. You allocated memory for `child->children` but not for the elements in the array. You can do this as follows:

```
for (int i=0;i<100;++i) {
  child->children[i] = new node;
}
```

By storing a `node *` you are storing the address of a `node` which contains the address of an array of addresses of `nodes`. This means that you need to allocated memory for all three levels of the hierarchy. You only allocated memory for two of the layers.

Comment: It works but is there any chance to make it easier without the for loop?

Comment: You only really have to allocate a node before you use it. You can also write in your code child->children[20] = new node; The problem with this is it becomes very hard to maintain which nodes have been allocated and which haven't.

Comment: So how can I make it easier to maintain? Is there any different way?

Comment: You can store your nodes in an std::vector<node> instead of a node **. This will alleviate most memory management.